# Layer length statistics in print composer QGIS

Tags: qgis, field-calculator, print-composer, spatial-database

In a QGIS composer, I would like to add a text label with the calculation of % of length of the total layer with a specific feature value.

My layer is composed of roads lines and I would like to know the proportion of the total length which have a specific value, like 'good' for the "ROADCONDITION" field.

For another question I had a good answer for count function:

```
'Existing roads: '
|| round(aggregate('releve_terrain','count', ' ',"ROADEXIS" = 'Yes') / layer_property('releve_terrain','feature_count') *100)  || '%'
```

I am looking for some help to use another function.

Comment: try using the 'sum' aggregate expression instead of 'count'

Comment: Do I need to create a field with length to do so? Then use something like
'Existing roads: '
|| round(aggregate('releve_terrain','sum', "length","ROADEXIS" = 'Yes') / layer_property('releve_terrain','feature_count') *100)  || '%'

Or the sum function works always with the $lenght ?

Comment: I would expect that function to work with $length, but the best way to find out is to try it out.